# '__' is not convertible to 'StringLiteralConvertible'

Tags: ios, swift

I don't understand why this code is producing an error:

```
Alamofire.request(Alamofire.Method.PATCH, "https://example.herokuapp.com/", parameters: [
            "format":"json",
            "todo":
                ["isComplete":todo?.isComplete],
            "id": todo?.id // <--- ERROR: is not convertible to 'StringLiteralConvertible'
            ]
        )
```

[image]

Comment: Try encoding your parameters. ` encoding: .JSON`

Comment: try     todo?.id as! String

Comment: You are asking people to help you with code that you are not showing, how would someone know what todo.id is?